# How to handle whisper in server side in laravel-echo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I'm building realtime chat system.

this is front-end code.

onload

```js
Echo.join(`chat.${id}`)
    .here(users => {})
    .listenForWhisper('sent', (e) => {});
```

on Sended

```js
Echo.join(`chat.${id}`)
    .whisper('sent', {
        message : message,
        sender : sender,
    });
```

What I want to do is to handle the 'sent' whisper event in laravel like this

```php
$message; // I want to get from whisper
$sender; // I want to get from whisper
Chat::create([
   "message" => $message,
   "sender" =>  $sender,
]);
```

But I don't how to implement this.
So, I'm coding like this so far.

on Sended

```js
Echo.join(`chat.${id}`)
    .whisper('sent', {
       "message" : message,
       "sender" : sender,
    });

axios.post('/message_sent', {
   message : message,
   sender : sender,
});
```

**api.php**

```php
Route::post('/message_sent', function(Request $request) {
  Chat::create([
      "message" => $request['message'],
      "sender" => $request['sender'],
  ]);
});
```

in this case, the message(from client to server) is sended by HTTP, not TCP/IP.

Any one knows how to get whisper value in server side??

Comment: are you using https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server?

Comment: @loic.lopez thanks for responding.no, I'm using `"laravel-echo": "^1.4.0"`.I didn' know this. thanks.

Comment: does I resolved your question? @Yoshihide Nishimoto

Comment: @loic.lopez No, I couldn't come up with how to do it by using laravel-echo-server.I'm using pusher, do you know the solution??

Comment: In my memory it is only possible to listen to the event "whisper" on the client side, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524551/laravel-echo-and-whisper

Comment: @loic.lopez Thanks.pusher's support says there are no way to do this on websocket.so I will do this by ajax.

Comment: can you validate my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `whisper` event is only a **client to client feature**, it is not possible at the moment to retrieve the event with the **Laravel Back-End**.

**See:** [laravel.com/docs/broadcasting#client-events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting#client-events)